# AIR ArgumentError: Error #2004: - Android

Tags: android, air, flash-cs6

**Getting this Error:**

```
ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.filesystem::File/set nativePath()
    at flash.filesystem::File()
    at TestingRandomSound_fla::MainTimeline/GetContents()[TestingRandomSound_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:22]
    at TestingRandomSound_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[TestingRandomSound_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:47]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at AppEntryCommon/run()
    at global/runtime::AndroidMobileDeviceAppEntry()
```

From this code:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    var myDocuments:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"\\sample");
```

It works on my Air Desktop but not with Android device.
I included the folder sample but it still is not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This works. But apparently files into the application directory are READ ONLY

```
var prefsFile:File = File.applicationDirectory;
prefsFile = prefsFile.resolvePath("assets/xml/preferences.xml");
```

I created a xml preferences file. But If I want to write on it I have to copy it into the documentsdirectory...